# Building BST in c++ with template

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

Im trying to implement a generic BST using template in c++.
However,
when I use gdb debug it. I find out that the whenever i called InsertNode, 
it treat t as NULL. 
When I step through the insertFunction, It runs correctly.
Is there any problem for declaration of tree when using template.

```
//
//  main.cpp
//  c++_project
//
//  Created by Timothy Leung on 5/5/13.
//  Copyright 2013 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename data_t>
struct nodeT{
    data_t data;
    nodeT *left, *right;
};

template <typename data_t>
nodeT<data_t> *FindNode(nodeT<data_t> *t, data_t data);

template <typename data_t>
void InsertNode(nodeT<data_t> *t, data_t data); 

template <typename data_t>
void display_tree(nodeT<data_t> *t);

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    cout << "Welcome to my BST! " << endl;
    nodeT<int> *tree;
    cout << "How many items do you have? \n";
    int num, temp;
    cin >> num;
    for (int i=0; i<num; ++i) {
        cout << "Number please :) \n";
        cin >> temp;
        InsertNode(tree, temp);
    }
    cout << "In order treeeeeee \n"<<endl;
    display_tree(tree);
}

template <typename data_t>
nodeT<data_t> *FindNode(nodeT<data_t> *t, data_t data){
    if(t==NULL) return NULL;
    if(data==t->data) return t;
    if (data < t->data) {
        FindNode(t->left, data);
    } else
        FindNode(t->right, data);
}

template <typename data_t>
void InsertNode(nodeT<data_t> *t, data_t data){
    if(t==NULL){
        t = new nodeT<data_t>;
        t->data = data;
        t->left = NULL;
        t->right = NULL;
        return;
    } 
    if(t->data < data){
        InsertNode(t->right, data);
    } else
        InsertNode(t->left, data);
}

template <typename data_t>
void display_tree(nodeT<data_t> *t){
    if (t!=NULL) {
        display_tree(t->left);
        cout << t->data << endl;
        display_tree(t->right);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`InsertNode(tree, temp);` passes `tree` by value, which means the changes you make occur a copy of `tree` that was set to its same value. It's the same reason that if you were to change `data` in the function, you would not be changing `temp`.

You either need to change `InsertNode` to take a reference or double pointer (so you pass by reference/address so the changes to the node are made obvious), or change `InsertNode` to return the newly created node (and assign it to `tree` (but make sure you only assign it the first time)).

Comment: ya.. you are right. correction void InsertNode(nodeT<data_t> * &t, data_t data);

Comment: but i don't understand. I pass t as a pointer, so when i amend it in insert node, shouldn't it got amended as well?

Comment: Ohh I get it. If I pass nodeT<data_t> *t, it is a copy of pointer. When I call new NodeT, it overwrite the *t with a new address, so the original pointer nvr changed

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke insertNode(t->right and t->left...), the right and left are always null.
You should create an instance for them first, like this:

```
t->right = new nodeT<data_t>;
insertNode(t->right,data);
```

Comment: when it is NULL, it hits the base case!

Comment: There is why your tree can never grow

Comment: When you invoke with t->right, it just pass a null into insertNode, it is not 't->right'